# sparse indexing in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, sparse-matrix

I have a very long code which is full of the following "if"s and matlab editor gives me a suggestion as follow:

**this sparse indexing expression is likely to be slow**

```
mt = rand(200,200);
[c r] = size(mt);
T = sparse(r*c,2);

for i = 1:c 
    for j = 1:r 
        if(ind(j,i)==1)
            templat = template + 1;
            T((i-1)*r+j,2)=100000;
        end
    end;
end;
```

Is there any way by which I can make the code faster and do the matlab's suggestion? (The code may not run, because I just picked a few lines and tried to show the issue)

Answer (score 2):

The nested `for`'s and `if` are equivalent to the following vectorized code:

```
[jj, ii] = find(ind==1); %// jj is rows, ii is columns
templat = template + numel(ii);
T((ii-1)*r+jj,2) = 10000;
```

Comment: Actually I have to use the nested for-loops. You can see the codes here and correcte your answer: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/94718193/code_sparse.m

Comment: @Sam That's a HUGE code! Do you expect us to look into the entire code?

Comment: No, at all, what I mean is that the code is not just a simple code that showed above. I need to use that nested for-loop code, because I need the indexe

Comment: @Sam "correct" my answer in which sense? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @LuisMendo: As I mentioned, I need to keep the for-loop, because I need it later. So, how I can keep the for loop and do the matlab's suggestion? (Thanks)

Comment: @Sam Matlab's suggestion is to remove the for loop! Your for loop and Luis' code do exactly the same thing. Maybe this means you can get rid of all the loops in your code!

Comment: @David: I need that for-loop for indexing and etc. and I think I cannot get rid of the loop!

Comment: @Sam Maybe ask a new question, because your current comments don't really make sense. The vectors `ii` and `jj` should be all the indices you need.