# faster sparse matric indexing in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, sparse-matrix

I had a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597271/sparse-indexing-in-matlab/26597380?noredirect=1#comment41850456_26597380) before but it was not as complete as this one! Actually, what I meant was that I have a nested if-for loop which I did not make it very clear before.

So, I have a very long code which is full of the following "if"s and matlab editor gives me a suggestion as follow:

**this sparse indexing expression is likely to be slow**

Is there any way by which I can make the code faster and do the matlab's suggestion? (The code may not run, because I just picked a few lines and tried to show the issue)

In my previous question, I did not explain that I need to use the i,j as index, so the answer was not convincing. But, as you can see here, I need to use the i and j as index which make the problem a little different from the previous post.

```
template = rand(200,200);
grid = rand(200,200);
T = size(template);
rws = size(grid,1);
cols = size(grid,2);
ind = "it is a matrix";

A = sparse(rws*cols,rws*cols);
T = sparse(rws*cols,2);

border_grid = 0;
border_template = 0;

template_comp = 0;
grid_comp = 0;


for i = 1:cols 
    for j = 1:rws 

        if(ind(j,i)==255)
           Asr=grid(j,i,1);
           Bsr=template(((j-posy)+1),((i-posx)+1),1); 
           Snorm= ((Asr-Bsr)^2)^(1/2);
            if (( (j+1) > 0) && ((j+1) <= rws))
                if ( ind(j+1,i)==0)
                    T((i-1)*rws+j,1)=100000; 
                    border_grid=border_grid+1;
                end

                if ( ind(j+1,i)==128)
                    border_template=border_template+1;
                    T((i-1)*rws+j,2)=100000; 
                end

                if( (ind(j+1,i)==255))
                    Atr=grid(j+1,i,1);
                    Btr=template(((j+1)-posy)+1,(i-posx)+1,1);
                    Tnorm= ((Atr-Btr)^2)^(1/2);
                    A((i-1)*rws+j,(i-1)*rws+(j+1))=Snorm+Tnorm;
                end
            end
        end;

        **+ some other similar if-loops**
    end
end
```

Comment: What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597271/sparse-indexing-in-matlab) question-answer given by @LuisMendo. That answer has two upvotes, but you haven't accepted it. So I guess there is some problem in that answer.

Comment: Yes, in that question I had not show the problem properly and I tried to delete the post, but I could not ! because it already had an answer

Comment: As you can see in the code, I need those i,j indexes and cannot get rid of for-loop. So, I am looking to make it faster and do the indexing faster

Comment: Please edit the question and link this question. Something like: "This question is related to [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597271/sparse-indexing-in-matlab). However <<state your concerns about that solution>>".